# node express express.static prevents access from root path '/'

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express and I have a catch all route

```
router.use('*',function(){...});
```

and a root route

```
router.use('/', function(){...});
```

I have this route placed after the

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

this causes my routes to not fire when placed below the previous line. however if I put my routes above it my catch all is also called on static asset requests. is there a way I can catch all requests except for the assets in my public folder including the route '/'? I don't want to resort to using regex and having to update it every time a directory is added to the public directory.

sorry for not being more details here are the relavant files

```
//app.js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

/* This is going to initialize the menubar for nwjs it is currently commented out as this is a non issue at this point
setTimeout(function () {

    //initialize passport
    var passport = require('./helpers/passport.js');
    //setup routes

    //setup window menu
    console = window.console;
    console.log(passport);
    passport.init(app);
    var gui = window.require('nw.gui');
    var win = gui.Window.get();
    var menu = new gui.Menu({
        type: 'menubar'
    });
    menu.createMacBuiltin('jist', {
        hideEdit: true,
        hideWindow: true
    });
    gui.Window.get().menu = menu;
},1000);*/
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');


// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});
module.exports = app;
//window.location.href="http://localhost:3000";
```

this is my index router

```
//routes/index.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
/* GET home page. */
router.use('*', function(req, res, nex){
    var path = req.originalPath;
    if(~['/users/login', '/users/signup'].indexOf(path) || req.user) return next();
    if(!req.user) return res.redirect('/users/login');
});
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Have you declared everything? `var router = express.Router()`, and did you mean app.use or router.use?

Comment: sorry for being unclear I have uploaded the two files

Comment: I figured it out very sorry I will take this question down because there are tons like it. I have been working all night at this only to realize that the foundation cli adds a index.html to public. because of this my static join was catching as a static file for '/' and in turn not using next.